# updating multiple rows C# database

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to update a table where it has a **network_name** ,say the LOAD table. Table Network has the same column too, **network_name**. Now how will I update the values on table LOAD if the same value was updated on table Network?

LOAD

```
network_name | product code |
-------------+--------------+
Talk & Text  | aaaaaaaaaaa
Talk & Text  | aaaaaaaaaaa
Touch Mobile | aaaaaaaaaaa
```

NETWORK

```
network_id |network_name | network code |
-----------+-------------+--------------+
12235      |Talk & Text  | aaaaaaaaaaa
23343      |Smart        | aaaaaaaaaaa
34343      |Touch Mobile | aaaaaaaaaaa
```

Now what if the Talk N Text is changed into TalkText, how will I update the Load table?

Comment: `UPDATE [LOAD] SET [network_name] = 'TalkText' WHERE [network_name] = 'Talk & Text'` ?  It's not clear what the problem is or why you can't update the data.

Comment: I recommend you read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - Rather than storing the verbatim text in each database record, you can store a link to the text that each record should use.  This way, if you need to change Talk & Text to TalkText, you only need to update one place.

Answer (score 1):

Add a primary/ID column to Load:

```
load_id | network_name   |  product_code |
--------+----------------+---------------+
0       | talk & text    | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
1       | touch & mobile | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
2       | smart          | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
```

Reference load_id from NETWORK:

```
network_id | load_id  |  network_code |
-----------+----------+---------------+
12235      | 0        | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
23343      | 2        | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
34343      | 1        | aaaaaaaaaaaa  |
```

Apply all updates to Load and use a SQL to link your results.

Answer (score 0):

In a normalized database, network_name doesn't really belong in the LOAD table as it's data related to a NETWORK entity.

If the LOAD table needs to have a relationship with the NETWORK table, then instead of having a network_name column in the LOAD table, use a network_id column instead.

Now you only have to update the NETWORK table if the network_name changes but the LOAD and NETWORK tables still have a relationship with each other.

If you want to normalize further then you could add a load_id column to the LOAD table, remove the network_id from the LOAD table and then create a new table which holds just the relationships between NETWORK and LOAD (i.e. a table with a network_id and load_id column) but whether you do that or not is down to your problem domain.